# Do detect as compelleted before runing an XHR in a controller Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest, phantomjs

I have an application which is using Angularjs. In each controller, I have a function that should run on route loading. I mean I want a constructor function in my controller. I want that the browser does not mark the page az completed page (ready document) before finishing that XHR request.

The reason is I`m using a system to render HTML snapshot of my pages, and I want to tell Phantomejs that the page is ready when the constructor XHR of each page (that I defined) has been finished.

Comment: This isn't really possible the way you describe it with AngularJs.  AngularJs isn't even bootstrapped until after `document.readyState` is set to `complete`.  https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap.  Perhaps it would be better if you showed some code of the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Sounds like what you want is to use `resolve` promises in your router. Not 100% clear what you are asking though or what the overall process flow you expect

Comment: @Claies  I added more info

Comment: Please [edit] the question and remove the **Answer** which is not an answer but additional information.